# Positive factors of $18150$ and $22000$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> How many positive factors do $18150$ and $22000$ share?

What would be the ideal way to go about this? If I prime factorize both I get $18150= 2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 11^2$  and $22000= 2^4 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 11$. Also if I take the greatest common divisor I get $gcd(18150, 22000) = 550$. Is the answer easily seen from here or am I missing something?

Comment: You are correct. It will be $\prod (a_i+1)$ where $a_i$ is the prime powers of $550$.

Comment: (where "the prime powers" means "the exponents in the prime factorization")

Answer (score 1):

The greatest common divisor 550 has all divisors which have 18150 and 22000 in common. If they had a common divisor which wouldn't be a divisor of 550, let's call it x, $lcm(550, x)$ would also divide both numbers and would be bigger than 550, which is a contradiction.

All you need to do is counting all divisors of 550. If I didn't forget any, there are 12 such divisors: 1, 2, 5, 10, 11, 22, 25, 55, 50, 110, 275, 550

Answer (score 0):

The shared factors are the factors of $550=2\cdot5^2\cdot11$, and there are $2\cdot3\cdot2$ of them.

Comment: Isn't there only $4$? $2, 5, 5, 11$?

Comment: @Daniel: what do you mean ? You are showing three distinct numbers.

Comment: Where did you get $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2$? I see that $550$ has $12$ factors now, but how did you come up with $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2$?

Comment: @Daniel: Hint: $(1+1)(2+1)(1+1)$. Every prime factor can appear with different multiplicities...